# C# dllimport problem with passing a float

Tags: c#, c, dllimport

I'm trying to get my dll import working.
This is the current import in C#

```
[DllImport(SpectrumDll, ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    //SCLIB_ERROR_CODE DLLEXPORT SPECTRUM_SetUserFloat(char *name, float value, int index); 
    public static extern SCLIB_ERROR_CODE SPECTRUM_SetUserFloat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name, float value, int index);
```

This is the C call from the dll header file.

```
SCLIB_ERROR_CODE DLLEXPORT SPECTRUM_SetUserFloat(char *name, float value, int index);
```

This is how I call it in code.

```
public bool SetUserFloat(string varName, float value, int index = 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = spectrum_dll_import.SPECTRUM_SetUserFloat(varName, value, index);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The function it self works, however it cuts off the part behind the comma.
So, If I want to write "5.343F", the value which the C DLL sets, is "5.000"

Is there something wrong with my "dllimport" and the "float" parameter?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Table 2.2 on the following page implies that you should use `double` on the c# side when the c function takes a float: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66244/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-2-Marshaling-Simple-Type

Comment: I already have tried that. In this case, it doesn't work at all. No value gets passed to the DLL when I use double. Thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine. We can only assume you are correct about return value type and `cdecl`. We can't verify that. But what we can verify is correct. If there is an error in the code you present, we don't have enough information to diagnose it. Most likely the code you present is correct and the DLL is rounding!

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan that's all I need to know! I also imported the DLL into LabView, there it's working fine. So I need to figure out where the problem comes from. Thank you, again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The calling convention will not make a difference because the c++ compiler he's using will most likely default to cdecl.

Comment: @Nina unless the DLLIMPORT macro specifies a calling convention, which it probably does.

Comment: Is DLL using a single (32 bits) or a double (64 bits)?  Is index correct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He's already set the calling convention to cdecl `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` I suppose he could try setting that to stdcall. jdweng also pointed out that the dll or his code could be a mismatch in architectures. In C++ the 64 bit dll will use the x64 ABI instead of cdecl.

Comment: @nina Yes. But we don't know the calling convention specified in the C++ code.

Comment: @jdweng float is 32 bit single precision in C++

Comment: That wasn't the question I asked.

Comment: @jdweng yes it was. The C++ code clearly uses float.

Comment: There is no place in the posting that shows any c language code that indicates the type.

Comment: @jdweng yes there is, second block of code

Comment: You should have documented the *varName* you used to get a better guess.  But this kind of api function is not uncommon, the programmer just did not want to commit to having a specific set of "user configurable" parameters.  You happened to use a varName that has an integral definition under the hood, something like "numberOfSamples" for example.  Nothing is wrong, keep going.

Comment: @jdweng It should be a 32bit / 4byte. At least LabView does pass a 4 byte numeric value. And with LabView it does work. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @hans passant the DLL sets a specific variable at a test system. The parameter varname is the name of the variable you want to update. The „value“ parameter is the value to be set for the variable. Hope this helps! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you present is correct in so far as we can tell. We can't verify the return type or the calling convention, so we will have to trust that you have translated them correctly. But we can state that the arguments are correctly translated in your pinvoke code.

The most likely explanation is simply that the DLL is truncating the value for this particular property.